# Rdkit - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: anaconda, rdkit

I have used `pip install rdkit-pypi` to install rdkit library. But when I type `import rdkit as rd`, it shows the error

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing rdBase: The specified module was not found.

I am using Anaconda as a base. What should I do to work with rdkit library?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I previously encountered this problem. After some reading, I came to know that the python version above 3.8.0 would not be compatible with rdkit. Even you need to change your base to rdkit.
I solve this by first downgrading the anaconda version with the python version lower than 3.8.0.
then I set my rdkit environment.

[In this image u can see my python version and I'm not getting any error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yAdG.png)

[In second image u can see my base to my-rdkit-envs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BDZn.png)